# Is L ample if $\dim \Gamma(X,L^{\otimes k}) \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety and $L$ a line bundle on it. Suppose that
$$
\dim \Gamma(X,L^{\otimes k}) \to \infty \text{ as } k \to \infty.
$$
Is $L$ ample?

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $\mathcal{O}(0,1)$ on $\Bbb P^1\times \Bbb P^1$. This is not ample, but the global sections of $\mathcal{O}(0,1)^{\otimes n} = \mathcal{O}(0,n)$ clearly satisfy the requested condition.

Comment: Very nice! Can you also find an example where X is a curve?

Comment: Do you mean for $X$ to be an irreducible curve? If not, there are silly things like taking $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ on two disjoint copies of $\Bbb P^1$.

Comment: Yes i mean irreducible :)

Comment: I don't think you can do this for irreducible projective curves, but I don't have a complete argument. Here's a sketch (no guarantees as to completeness/correctness): the fact that the dimension of global sections of tensor powers goes off to infinity should imply the line bundle is of positive degree and thus by Riemann-Roch, it must eventually be very ample, thus the original line bundle was ample.